# How to import a table containing mixtures of mixtures to access, and expand this table to

Tags: microsoft-access, database

I have bunch of data detailing compositions of materials.  Some of these materials are also mixtures of other materials.  The data I have is tabulated as below.  (the ingredient type is just for ease of human reading, it expresses whether the value in column B exists in column A)

I wanted to expand this to the bottom level, that is to say, return a table which shows the composition in terms of just the "things" not the mixes; where something is a mix, it should expand to it's constituent "things"

In excel this would require some slow running and convoluted VBA.  From what I understand, this should be relatively trivial to do in access, if the data was presented in such a way that access "understands" it.  But I have no idea how.

```
Product         Ingredient      Ingredient Type
APPLE_PIE       APPLE_FILLING   mix            
APPLE_PIE       PASTRY          mix            
APPLE_FILLING   APPLES          thing          
APPLE_FILLING   SUGAR           thing          
APPLE_FILLING   MIXED_SPICE     mix            
MIXED_SPICE     CINAMON         thing          
MIXED_SPICE     NUTMEG          thing          
PASTRY          FLOUR           thing          
PASTRY          SALT            thing          
PASTRY          WATER           thing          
PASTRY          BUTTER          thing          
EGG_NOG         EGGS            thing          
EGG_NOG         MILK            thing          
EGG_NOG         MIXED_SPICE     mix            
EGG_NOG         RUM             mix            
RUM             SUGAR           thing          
RUM             TIME            thing          
RUM             RAINBOWS        thing
```

An elegant solution would work no matter how deep the "blend of blends" goes, and not require any manual refactoring of data.  But something which expands the table 1 level and can be ran recursively would still do the job.

Comment: I am the classic case of an excel user performing data analysis that's getting more and more complex to the point of using so many bolted on macros and contrived formulae that I may as well be using a database.  I've known for a while that I should be making the jump to access.  This next task is something I could achieve using VBA and other dirty tricks, but from what I understand about relational databases, Access is really is what I should be using.  Any pointers will be greatly appreciated

Comment: This can be done with a query with a clause for the ingredient type to be 'thing'. Someone with vba and excel background, have you worked with odbc before?

Comment: I have a little.  The data actually comes from an ODBC connection funnily enough.  A query you say...

Comment: I could try an answer, but will see if this is enough. Go to a blank cell, select data then  From other sources, from Microsoft query. This will bring up the wizard. Select your odbc source, select the table, then select the column(s) you want. Next 2 windows are for filter and sort.  Try these options to see if you can get what you want.

Comment: @bvaughn, maybe I'm misunderstanding you here, but I'm not looking just to filter a list, I want express everything in column A as its base constituent parts, rather than as blends of these.

Comment: So the plan is Data -> Excel and then Excel breaks Mixes down to things, and then everything is restated as Things only.  Is that correct?